# Push files to Git remote whenever I want but do not track them

Tags: git, github

I am using Gulp, which helps compile my coffeescript to javascript and build javascript modules to a single, huge javascript file `bundle.js` via Webpack.

During development I do not want to push the large `bundle.js` to Github everytime I commit (because it will change according to the source files).

But in production phase, I would like to push the `bundle.js` to Github, then on my production server I can immediately pull it from master of Github and do not need to set up the Gulp and compile again.

Can Git do this? Or am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: Can `git` do this? Yes. Is it the best way to accomplish what you want? My opinion would tend towards "no"...

Comment: Any better way to do this?

Comment: Is your "production server" in the same network as your development system? Why not just push the build product directly to your "production server", instead of going through an external intermediary like Github? If direct access between the two isn't possible, then using an intermediary more suited for simple file transfer (something like Dropbox or what-not) would be better than polluting your source code repository with a trail of build products. Unless you might ever have to roll production back to an exact version, in which case you might want to track release bundles...

Comment: Yes you are right... It makes no sense to use git on a production server actually! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `git update-index --assume-unchanged bundle.js` to ignore it temporarily, then `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged bundle.js` to track it again.  Note that this means it won't get committed (not just "not pushed").  I'm pretty sure there is no way to commit a file but exclude it from the push (since you're pushing commits, not files), but if you don't commit it, it won't get pushed.

Of course, you can also simply not `git add` it, so it won't be committed, but if you're using `git commit -a` or `git add .`, it can be useful to `git update-index --assume-unchanged` the files you don't want to commit.